# Retrieving default property names

Tags: powershell

The following command:

`Get-ChildItem | Get-Member`

shows that there are of course many properties on `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` and `System.IO.FileInfo`.

But, when run interactively, only the properties `Mode`, `LastWriteTime`, `Length`, and `Name` are shown. These are also the properties shown when `Get-ChildItem` is piped to `Format-Table` or `Out-GridView`.

My question is, is there a way to get the names of these default properties in a programmatic way for any given object? I.e. something like this:

```
Get-DefaultProperties @(Get-ChildItem)[0]
```

Should return the following in an array: `Mode LastWriteTime Length Name`

Answer (score 5):

### Built-In Solution

Below is a simple, programmatic way to access the default properties.

```
(Get-Item -Path $FolderPath).PSStandardMembers
```

The resulting output will be either a ***DefaultDisplayProperty*** or a ***DefaultDisplayPropertySet***.

---

```
DefaultDisplayProperty  
----------------------   
Name
```

***OR***

```
PSStandardMembers {DefaultDisplayPropertySet}
```

---

In the second case, you can access the underlying properties like so:

```
(Get-Item -Path $FilePath).PSStandardMembers.DefaultDisplayPropertySet
```

---

```
ReferencedPropertyNames : {LastWriteTime, Length, Name}  
MemberType              : PropertySet   
Value                   : DefaultDisplayPropertySet {LastWriteTime, Length, Name}   
TypeNameOfValue         : System.Management.Automation.PSPropertySet   
Name                    : DefaultDisplayPropertySet   
IsInstance              : False
```

---

You could then use dot-notation to get into the ***ReferencedPropertyNames*** array directly.

Answer (score 3):

To understand what object properties PowerShell outputs, you should read 
[about_Types.ps1xml](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847881.aspx):

> The Types.ps1xml file in the Windows PowerShell installation directory
>   ($pshome) is an XML-based text file that lets you add properties and 
>   methods to the objects that are used in Windows PowerShell. Windows 
>   PowerShell has built-in Types.ps1xml files that add several elements
>   to the .NET Framework types, but you can create additional
>   Types.ps1xml files to further extend the types.

For example, you will find a `FileSystem.format.ps1xml` within your PowerShell directory (`%windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`) containing a definition for  `System.IO.DirectoryInfo`:

```
<TableColumnItems>
    <TableColumnItem>
        <PropertyName>Mode</PropertyName>
    </TableColumnItem>
    <TableColumnItem>
        <ScriptBlock>
            [String]::Format("{0,10}  {1,8}", $_.LastWriteTime.ToString("d"), $_.LastWriteTime.ToString("t"))
        </ScriptBlock>
    </TableColumnItem>
    <TableColumnItem>
    <PropertyName>Length</PropertyName>
    </TableColumnItem>
    <TableColumnItem>
        <PropertyName>Name</PropertyName>
    </TableColumnItem>
</TableColumnItems>
```

But to your question, beside parsing the `ps1xml`, I don't know a clean programmatic way to get the "default" properties. You could select the first element of your desired object and use `Out-String` to get a string which you can parse:

```
((((Get-ChildItem)[0]) | out-string).Trim() -split "`n" | select -index 3).Trim() -split '\s+'
```

**Output:**

```
Mode
LastWriteTime
Length
Name
```

Be aware that this may not work with other objects...

Answer (score 1):

`Get-childitem` will produce different types of objects based on your location. If you are in the registry it will produce RegistryKey objects while if you are in the file system you will get FileInfo or DirectoryInfo objects.

The `FileSystem.Format.ps1xml` file (that you can find in `$pshome`) defines the display of file system objects such as file and directory objects. If you look at the ViewDefinitions you'll find the values used by the default formater.

As far as I know, there aren't ways to find these default values without "parsing" that file but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but since I came here with the same question and the answers given didn't work for me, I came up with this solution:

```
($obj | Format-Table)[0].shapeInfo.tableColumnInfoList.propertyName
```

This returns the default properties of `$obj` outputted by `Format-Table` when piped in. Note that you have to pass in an object and not a Cmdlet, since the returned type might depend on the context as David noted.