# Why does "Get-ChildItem -File | Get-FileHash" work?

Tags: powershell

I'm more familiar with Bash than with Powershell and sometimes I get confused by the latter's object model.

Looking at the [documentation of Get-FileHash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash?view=powershell-7), it seems that there are 3 ways of specifying the input:

- Get-FileHash [-Path]
- Get-FileHash [-LiteralPath]
- Get-FileHash [-InputStream]

The first two take file names, the third a stream of data.

Now, [`Get-ChildItem -File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7) seems to output [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.8) objects, judging from what [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member?view=powershell-7) says:

```
$ Get-ChildItem -File | Get-Member
TypeName: System.IO.FileInfo
```

And yet the pipeline `Get-ChildItem -File | Get-FileHash` works correctly. My question is, what is the mechanism that allows converting `System.IO.FileInfo` to the type of inputs expected by `Get-FileHash`?

Comment: Maybe [Retrieving default property names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38137864/205233) has the answer ...

Comment: @Filburt: The linked post is about (display) _formatting_, whereas this question is about _parameter binding_.

Comment: See also a blog post about [Type Conversion Magic](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/understanding-powershells-type-conversion-magic/) by Lee Holmes (MS PowerShell dev team).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The **[`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo)** / **[`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo)** instances output by PowerShell cmdlets have a **`.PSPath` property**<sup>[*]</sup>  that contains the instances' fully qualified path, which is the full file-system path prefixed by the PS provider name (e.g., `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\windows`).

***File-processing* cmdlets** such as `Get-FileHash` have a **`-LiteralPath`** parameter ***which has an alias name of `-PSPath`***.

Because a `-LiteralPath` parameter (typically) **accepts input from the pipeline *by property name*, input objects that have a `.PSPath` property automatically bind to it**, by virtue of the `PSPath` parameter alias name.

As an aside:

- File-processing cmdlets also have a **`-Path`** parameter, which interprets its arguments as [*wildcard* expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards), not as literal paths.

  - When you pipe path *strings* to such cmdlets, they bind to `-Path`, which notably means that they are indeed interpreted as wildcards - while this will typically not matter, because most literal paths do not contain wildcard metacharacters, it does with paths that contain `[` and `]`, which are then misinterpreted; avoiding this misinterpretation requires escaping them as `` `[ `` and `` `] ``, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70413617/45375).
- Due to a bug in *Windows PowerShell* (since fixed in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*), `Get-FileHash`, specifically, doesn't accept strings *via the pipeline* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69922416/45375) for details.

---

**How to discover** this behavior:

- Via the [online help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash?view=powershell-7):

[image: parameter description]

- Programmatically:

  - Note: `Get-Help Get-FileHash -Parameter LiteralPath | Select-Object name, aliases, pipelineinput` works too in *this* case, but this approach is generally restricted to target commands that come with [MAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Assistance_Markup_Language)-based help files, and even those that do can have help files that are *out of sync* with the actual command definition.

```bash
& {
  Get-Command $args[0] | % Parameters | % $args[1] |
  Select-Object Name, Aliases, @{
    n = 'Accepts pipeline input';
    e = { $(if ($_.Attributes.ValueFromPipeline) { 'by value' }), $(if ($_.Attributes.ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName) { 'by property name' }) -join ', ' -replace '^, ' }
  }
} Get-FileHash LiteralPath
```

Output:

```
Name        Aliases      Accepts pipeline input
----        -------      ----------------------
LiteralPath {PSPath, LP} by property name
```

---

<sup>[*] It is PowerShell's file-system provider that adds this property, among others. *All* PowerShell [providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers) decorate their output items this way, such as the `Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey` instances output by the *registry* provider. The underlying .NET types do *not* have it. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55881978/45375) for more information.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

From the About Functions Advanced Parameters documentation, [*ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName* argument section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters#valuefrompipelinebypropertyname-argument):

> The ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName argument indicates that the
>   parameter accepts input from a property of a pipeline object. The
>   object property must have the same name or alias as the parameter.
>
> For example, if the function has a ComputerName parameter, and the
>   piped object has a ComputerName property, the value of the
>   ComputerName property is assigned to the function's ComputerName
>   parameter.

**Update**: Originally linked the wrong source code file. The correct [`Get-FileHash` source code is here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/GetHash.cs). As [@mklement0 ***correctly answered***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60177977/604196) the `Get-ChildItem` *cmdlet* outputs an object with a `PSPath` property, which makes this work.

Comment: Strangely, path doesn't work.  `[pscustomobject]@{path='there'}  | get-filehash`

Comment: @js2010 in Powershell 5.1, `Accept pipeline input: False` for parameter `Path`. See also `(Get-Command Get-FileHash).Definition`

Comment: @JosefZ - thanks for the correction! `[pscustomobject]@{LiteralPath='PATH'} | Get-FileHash`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it uses the pspath property.

```
dir there | select pspath | get-filehash

Algorithm  Hash                                                                Path
---------  ----                                                                ----
SHA256     44723DD4D0E0D46A3C7FA8ACA254B61C27B6B5789F96177E82C80700409F1535    C:\users\...
```