# powershell array - not pulling name object

Tags: powershell

I have the script where it captures blank profile paths in the profile list. I am not sure how to call the array and delete the whole key. It is saying path is not found as it is trying to run it from c:\windows\system32

how do i get it to go through the different paths it might have ? Right now I am just testing by blanking out one profile path

```
$Profiles = get-childitem “HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList”

$ProfileData = @()

foreach($Profile in $Profiles){
$ThisProfileInfo = $null

$ThisProfileInfo = @{Name=$Profile.Name;

                    ProfilePath=$Profile.GetValue("ProfileImagePath")}

   if (!($ThisProfileInfo.ProfilePath)) {
   $ProfileData += $ThisProfileInfo
}

}

$ProfileData

ForEach-Object{Remove-Item -Path ($Object.name)}
```

the error is ForEach-Object{Remove-Item -Path ($Object.name)}

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                  
----                           -----                                                                                                                                  
Name                           HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-115761338-1150813220-1225219381-227283            
ProfilePath                                                                                                                                                           
Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows 
NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-115761338-1150813220-1225219381-227283' because it does not exist.
At line:24 char:16
+ ForEach-Object{Remove-Item -Path ($Object.name)}
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\WINDOWS\syst...25219381-227283:String) [Remove-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

Comment: can you share the error code? So, you just want to delete the keys that are added to `$ProfileData` due to null values?

Comment: I wanted both in there to just be a visual check. I would remove it afterwards. I am trying to delete the whole registry if it finds blank. That full path is found in the name. But if you run the remove-item it is not doing that. I have edited the question and added the error. You see it puts the c:\windows\system32 in front. I am not sure why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

The following removes all registry keys representing user profiles that have no / an empty `ProfileImagePath` value:

```sh
# Note: Run with elevation, otherwise Remove-Item will fail.
Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" |
  Where-Object { -not $_.GetValue('ProfileImagePath') } |
    Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

---

Your primary problem is that the `.Name` property of items representing registry keys is a registry-native key path (e.g. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-18`), which PowerShell's [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item) doesn't recognize as such<sup>[1]</sup> and interprets *as a relative file-system path*.

<sup>There's also an incidental *syntax problem* in your question, as of this writing: your last two statements should be a single pipeline, as follows:

`$ProfileData | ForEach-Object{ Remove-Item -Path $_.Name }`</sup>

Piping the `Get-ChildItem` output directly to `Remove-Item` avoids this problem, because it binds the `.PSPath` property values to `Remove-Item`'s `-LiteralPath` parameter, and `.PSPath` contains a *[provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers)-qualified* path, i.e. it has a prefix that identifies the path as a *registry* path; e.g. `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-18`

For details on where the `.PSPath` property values come from and how they bind to the 
`-LiteralPath` parameter of PowerShell's provider cmdlets, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60177977/45375).

---

<sup>[1] There is one exception: If the current location (as reflected in `$PWD` / `Get-Location`) *happens to be the root of the targeted registry hive* (which would be unusual, because *registry* locations are rarely made the current location), the registry-native path *is* recognized. E.g, if you changed to the root of the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` hive with `Set-Location HKLM:\`, 

`Get-ChildItem HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` would work (with or without the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\` prefix).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to troubleshoot by running just:

```
get-childitem “HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList”
```

When I ran this, I got two fields: `Name` and `Property`. The name field only had the name of the key, but when I ran:

```
get-childitem “HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList” | select Name
```

I was able to get the full path to the key, which may be why the prior method wasn't working. Might just need to add `| select Name`.

Comment: I wanted both in there to just be a visual check. I would remove it afterwards. I am trying to delete the whole registry if it finds blank. That full path is found in the name. But if you run the remove-item it is not doing that.

Comment: I think you want remove-itemproperty then

Comment: mattmoore5553 is already using `.Name` - i.e. the full registry key path - in his attempt. The core problem is that you cannot pass such a path directly to `Remove-Item`, because it will interpret it as a relative file-system path. As an aside: if you wanted just the `Name` property _value_, you'd need `| select -ExpandProperty Name`.