# Powershell: "remove-item $object" vs "$object | remove-item"

Tags: powershell

```
PS C:\Users\robert.lee> new-item C:\temp\junk\delete-me
PS C:\Users\robert.lee> $d=get-childitem C:\temp\junk -file
PS C:\Users\robert.lee> remove-item $d
```

/* This does NOT delete C:\temp\junk\delete-me, but deletes C:\Users\robert.lee\delete-me. */

```
PS C:\Users\robert.lee> $d | remove-item
```

/* This does delete C:\temp\junk\delete-me. */

Why `remove-item $d` does not know where to find the file (`C:\temp\junk`) while `$d | remove-item` does? The object $d has the full path in either case.

PS: `remove-item $d` does remove file in another location, as tested on PSVersion 7.2.1 on macOS Monterey:

```
PS /Users/robert.lee/m/Windows> $d=get-childitem /tmp/Junk2 -file  
PS /Users/robert.lee/m/Windows> ls /tmp/Junk2 
delete-me
PS /Users/robert.lee/m/Windows> remove-item $d
PS /Users/robert.lee/m/Windows> ls /tmp/Junk2 
PS /Users/robert.lee/m/Windows>
```

Comment: take a look at how the `fileinfo` object converts to a string. it DOES NOT include the full set of info you expect ... but when you pipe to the cmdlet, that cmdlet gets the `fileinfo` object, not a stringified version of the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell can only do so much for you, and one thing it can't do, is guess what you're after all the time. The issue you're having comes from the parameter binding going on behind the scenes. So, the binding with `Remove-Item $g` only happens to the `Name` property from the `[FileInfo]` object passed to it, which will coerce the object into a string and then tie it to the current working directory binding it to *Path*.

Whereas, `$g | Remove-Item`, the binding from the *pipeline* is bound using a different procedure and takes the *PSPath* instance member and binds it to the *LiteralPath* which is the *FullName* property in your `[FileInfo]` object.

- *Still coerces the object into an object of `[string]`, just using a different property.*
- Sauce for an *okay* understanding of [*ParameterBinding*](https://4sysops.com/archives/understanding-powershell-pipeline-parameter-binding/).

  - Using [`Trace-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/trace-command?view=powershell-7.2), you can get a much better understanding of this.

---

*Long story short, use `$g.FullName` for both scenarios as it will output an object of `[string]`, and both *Path* parameters accept the entirety of the value, by pipeline as well.*

Comment: Some great pointers, but let me clarify re argument-based binding: It isn't technically, the `.Name` property
that binds, it is the result of a `.ToString()` call, which - in Windows PowerShell only - _situationally_ reports
either the value of `.Name` or `.FullName` in `Get-ChildItem` output, _depending on the specifics of the call_.
`$g.FullName` (or, to support all providers, `$g.PSPath`) should only be used as an _argument_ with `-LiteralPath`.
If you use it via the _pipeline_, it binds to `-Path`, risking unintended interpretation as wildcards with paths
that contain `[`

Comment: (Finally, a quibble: `.PSPath` isn't just the `.FullName` value, it is that value (more generally, the provider-native path value)  _with a PS provider prefix_, e.g. `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\foo\bar.txt`)

Comment: @mklement0, just reiterating what I saw through `Trace-Command -Name (Get-TraceSource).Name -Expression { Remove-Item $g }`. Didn't want to do a long post and include everything lol also, didn't realize you could use `$g.PSPath` instead. Cool indeed

Answer (score 3):

To complement [Abraham Zinala's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72107723/45375) with some **background information**:

**From a usability perspective, `$d | Remove-Item` and `Remove-Item $d` *should* work the same**; the reasons they don't are (written as of PowerShell Core 7.2.3):

- ***Argument*-based parameter binding is, unfortunately, less sophisticated than *pipeline*-based binding**:

  - Notably, the `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName` property on the `-LiteralPath` parameter, whose alias is `-PSPath`, is only honored for input objects provided *via the pipeline* (`$d | Remove-Item`) and not also when provided as an *argument* (`Remove-Item $d`).
  - With pipeline input, it is the `.PSPath` property that PowerShell's [provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers) cmdlets decorate their output objects with that robustly binds to `-LiteralPath`, because the `.PSPath` property value is a *full, provider-qualified path* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60177977/45375) for a detailed explanation.
  - This binding asymmetry is the subject of [GitHub issue #6057](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6057).
- If you **pass a file- or directory-info object as an *argument*** and you do so *positionally* (i.e. without preceding the argument with the target-parameter name):

  - It is the [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards)-based `-Path` parameter that is targeted:

    - This is normally not a problem, but does become one if the intended-as-literal path happens to contain `[` characters (e.g., `c:\foo\file[1].txt`), given that `[` is a metacharacter in PowerShell's wildcard language.
    - Using a *named* argument that explicitly targets the `-LiteralPath` parameter avoids this problem (note that PowerShell (Core) 7+ allows you to shorten to `-lp`):

      ```sh
      # Note: Still not robust in *Windows PowerShell* - see below.
      Remove-Item -LiteralPath $d
      ```
  - Both `-Path` and `-LiteralPath` are `[string[]]`-typed, i.e. they accept an array of *strings*, which in *argument*-based parameter binding means that **any non-string argument is simply *stringified*** (loosely speaking, like calling `.ToString()` on it)<sup>[1]</sup>:

    - **In *Windows PowerShell* - as you've experienced - this can lead to subtle but potentially destructive bugs** - because **[`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) and [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo) instances *situationally* stringify to only their `.Name` property**, not to their `.FullName` property - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400031/45375) for details.
    - **In *PowerShell (Core) 7+* this is no longer a problem** - stringification now consistently uses `.FullName`.
    - However, **stringification can still lead to failure for items returned by a PowerShell provider *other* than the file-system one**, such as the registry provider:

      ```sh
      # !! The 2nd command fails, because $regItem stringifies to
      # !! "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console" (the registry-native path),
      # !! which Get-Item then misinterprets as a relative file-system path.
      $regItem = Get-Item HKCU:\Console
      Get-Item $regItem
      ```

---

The **upshot**:

For **target cmdlets that have `-Path` / `-LiteralPath` parameters**, provide arguments that are provider items, such as output by [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) and [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item):

- **preferably *via the pipeline***:

  ```sh
  # Robust, in both PowerShell editions.
  Get-ChildItem C:\temp\junk -file | Remove-Item
  ```
- **If you must use an *argument***, target **`-LiteralPath`** explicitly, and **use the `.PSPath` property**:

  ```sh
  # Robust, in both PowerShell editions.
  $d = Get-ChildItem C:\temp\junk -file
  Remove-Item -LiteralPath $d.PSPath
  ```

If, by contrast, you need to **pass the paths of provider items to *.NET APIs* or *external programs***:

- Since `.PSPath` values contain a PowerShell *provider prefix* (e.g., `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::`) in front of the item's native path, such values aren't directly understood by outside parties.
- The robust approach is to **pipe a provider item to [`Convert-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/convert-path)** in order to **convert it to a native path in isolation** (piping again results in robust `.PSPath` binding to `-LiteralPath`):

  ```sh
   $d | Convert-Path # -> 'C:\temp\junk\delete-me'
  ```

  - This also works with path strings that are based on [PowerShell-only drives](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive), e.g:

    ```sh
    Convert-Path -LiteralPath HKCU:\Console # -> 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console'
    ```

---

<sup>[1] For most .NET types, PowerShell indeed calls `.ToString()`, but requests *culture-invariant* formatting, where supported, via the `IFormattable` interface; for select types, notably arrays and `[pscustomobject]`, it uses custom stringification in lieu of calling `.ToString()` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732/45375) for details.</sup>