# Stumped on PowerShell ForEach loop not working as expected

Tags: powershell, foreach

I want to traverse all subdirectories and make a file called `.hidden` containing all the directory's files and folders which have the Windows hidden attribute, so that they are hidden in Linux desktop environments as well (shared directories in dual-boot).

The elements of this script work in the command line, but I cannot work out why the script itself doesn't work. It just results in a single empty `.hidden` file in the top parent directory.

```
$param1=$args[0]
Get-ChildItem -Path $param1 -Directory -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Hidden -Force -Name | Out-File '.hidden'
}
```

Comment: You need to provide a full path for our `Out-File`. Try `ForEach($Directory in (gci $param1 -dir -rec)){GCI $Directory.FullName -hidden -force -name | Out-File "$($Directory.FullName)\.hidden"}` so that way you can reference the folder after the pipe inside the loop.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician, that's an effective solution, but note that using `$_` isn't a problem in a nested pipeline as long as you don't try to use it in a  _script block_, which isn't necessary here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `'.hidden'` as the output file path, which invariably targets the *same* output file in the *current* location (directory).

Instead, you must specify a path to *each directory at hand*, which is accessible via `$_.FullName`:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $param1 -Force -Directory -Recurse |
  ForEach-Object {  
    if ($hiddenItems = $_ | Get-ChildItem -Hidden -Force -Name) {
      $hiddenItems | 
        Out-File -LiteralPath (Join-Path $_.FullName '.hidden') -WhatIf
    }
  }
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf` and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Note:

- You can speed up the file-writing command with
  `Set-Content -LiteralPath (Join-Path $_.FullName '.hidden') -Value $hiddenItems`, but note that in Windows PowerShell `Set-Content` uses a different character encoding by default - see the bottom section for more information.
- With *literal* paths, it's better to use `-LiteralPath` rather than `-Path`, so as to prevent inadvertent interpretation of such paths as [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) patterns.
- `$_ | Get-ChildItem ...` is shorthand for `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_.FullName ...`, for the reasons explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60177977/45375).
- As per your later request, the above command only creates an output file for subdirectories that contain at least one hidden item, hence the `if ($hiddenItems = $_ | Get-ChildItem -Hidden -Force -Name) { ... }` statement.

  - Note that `=` in PowerShell is always an *assignment* statement and that in the context of `(...)` the assigned value is *passed through*, which in the context of a *conditional* such as with `if` causes that value to be coerced to a `[bool]`; if the value is the output from a command that happens to produce *no output*, `$false` is implied; if there *is* output, `Get-ChildItem` outputting at least one object implies `$true`. In general, however, even non-empty output can result in `$false`: see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375) for a summary of PowerShell's to-Boolean conversion rules.
- As an aside:

  - In [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), `$_` rather than `$_.FullName` would be sufficient in the [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path) call, because in .NET (Core),  [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo) (as output by [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) and reflected in their `.Parent` property) *consistently* stringify to their full path.

    - For the same reason, `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_` would work reliably in PowerShell (Core), but not in Windows PowerShell (see next point);
      `$_ | Get-ChildItem` works reliably in *both* PowerShell editions.
  - By contrast, in *Windows PowerShell*, `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` instances (as well as [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instances) *situationally* stringify to their *name only* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400031/45375).

---

**Workaround for *Windows PowerShell* if creation of BOM-less UTF-8 files is a must / controlling the output encoding:**

- In *Windows PowerShell*, `Out-File` as well as `>` default to UTF-16LE files. While you can create UTF-8 files by adding `-Encoding utf8`, they  will invariably have a *BOM*; while `Set-Content` produces ANSI-encoded files by default, it also invariably creates a BOM with `-Encoding utf8`.

  - As an aside: you wouldn't have that problem in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), where BOM-less UTF-8 is the consistent default.
- The command below creates *BOM-less* UTF-8 files even in Windows PowerShell, taking advantage of the (surprising) fact that `New-Item` (invariably) creates such files, as explained in detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66553739/45375). It also uses Unix-format LF-only newlines (`` "`n" ``)

```bash
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $param1 -Force -Directory -Recurse |
  ForEach-Object {  
    if ($hiddenItems = $_ | Get-ChildItem -Hidden -Force -Name) {
      # Creates BOM-less UTF-8 files.
      New-Item -Force (Join-Path $_.FullName '.hidden') -Value ($hiddenItems -join "`n")
    }
  }
```

Note: If you need your files to have a *trailing newline*, replace `` ($hiddenItems -join "`n") `` with `` (($hiddenItems -join "`n") + "`n") ``

Comment: Looks like it worked, thanks for accepting, @paradroid; however, it occurred to me that it should be `$_.FullName`, not `$_.FullName` to construct the output file with, right? I've updated the answer accordingly, but tell me if I got something wrong.

Comment: Hmmn,I am finding a couple of problems. The `.hidden` files aren't being created in all directories that contain hidden files, but I cannot see a pattern so far. Also, the `.hidden` files are encoded with UTF-16, where Linux expects UTF-8.

Comment: @paradroid, I have no explanation for missing directories: `-Force` tells `Get-ChildItem` to also consider hidden items; if there are no permissions issue and it still misses directories, it would be a bug.

Comment: @paradroid, in _Windows PowerShell_, `Out-File` (as well as `>`) defaults to UTF-16LE files. You can create UTF-8 files by adding `-Encoding utf8`, but note that the file will invariably have a _BOM_. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66553739/45375) for workarounds. As an aside: you wouldn't have that problem in [_PowerShell (Core) 7+_](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), where BOM-less UTF-8 is the consistent default.

Comment: When I upgrade to PowerShell Core, would there be any reason to still keep a tab configuration for Windows PowerShell in Windows Terminal settings? I am also unsure that PowerShell Core would be used when the script is called for through the bash script on WSL (which is how it is to triggered).

Comment: @paradroid, since PowerShell (Core) isn't fully backward compatible with Windows PowerShell and since there are modules that only work in the latter, you may still have a need to use Windows PowerShell. PowerShell (Core)'s CLI is `pwsh.exe`, which is distinct from Windows PowerShell's CLI, `powershell.exe`. Note that you can also install PowerShell (Core) natively inside WSL.

Comment: I think the most portable way of doing this would be to use Windows PowerShell, but I'm having difficulty getting the utf8 no-BOM workaround to work. Could you add it to your answer? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @paradroid, please see the new bottom section I've added to the answer.

Comment: The `.hidden` files don't work with CRLF line endings either. I have tried the solution I have found with `-join "`n"` but my experiments aren't working. Sorry about the hassle.

Comment: @paradroid, ``-join "`n"`` should work - please see my update.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is the completed script, made with help from ChatGPT: http://ix.io/4Crs Cheers.