# When using Get-ChildItem can the Remove-Item path be inferred somehow?

Tags: powershell

When using `Get-ChildItem`, I have to duplicate the path to the files when trying to delete them. I was just curious in the `Remove-Item` if it's inferred somewhere.

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp\test" | 
Foreach-Object {
    Remove-Item "c:\temp\test\$($_.Name)" -WhatIf
    //can it be something like:
    Remove-Item $_
}
```

Comment: I didn't get it. Do you mean `$_.FullName`?  ‍♂️ And why don't just pipe it to `Remove-Item`?

Comment: This worked! `$_ | Remove-Item -WhatIf -Force -Recurse` if you add your answer I will mark it. Thanks!

Comment: It's ok. I'm glad it helped.  

Comment: The issue is likely due to FileSystemInfo instances defaulting to their `.Name` property instead of `.FullName` when converted to string and is only an issue in Windows PowerShell (.NET Framework) but, as Olaf mentioned, the way to do it is to pipe the output from `Get-ChildItem` directly to `Remove-Item`, no `ForEach-Object` is needed.

Comment: `get-childitem c:\temp\test | remove-item -whatif`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on the helpful comments:

- The ***immediate* answer** to your question is:

  - **Use `$_.FullName`** to *predictably* get the *full file / directory path*.

    - [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) emits [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) and [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo) instances and `.FullName` is the property that contains their full (absolute) path.
    - By passing the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) containing an instance of these types *as whole* to `Remove-Item`, you *implicitly stringify it*, because it (positionally) binds to the `-Path` parameter, which is `[string[]]`-typed (it accepts an *array* of file-system paths).

      - Sadly, in *Windows PowerShell* this stringification *situationally* (as in your case) results in the file/directory's *name only* rather than the full path - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400031/45375) for details.
      - Fortunately, in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) stringification of these type now *consistently* results in their *full path*, i.e. the value of their `.FullName` property.
  - Use `$_.FullName` **with [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item)'s `-LiteralPath` parameter** to ensure that it is used *literally* (verbatim).

    - The `-Path` parameter, which is also targeted *positionally* by the (first) unnamed argument (as in your case), interprets its arguments as [wildcard patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards), which is notably problematic with file paths that contain `[` and `]`, because these characters are wildcard *metacharacters* that would require *escaping* in order to be treated literally.
    - This distinction between `-Path` and `-LiteralPath` applies to *all* [provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers) cmdlets, including `Get-ChildItem` itself.
- The ***better* answer** is:

  - **Pipe your `Get-ChildItem` output *directly* to `Remove-Item`**.

    ```bash
    # NOTE: -Recurse is needed if *nonempty subdirs.* are among the children.
    #       Use Get-ChildItem -File / -Directory to only list files / subdirs.
    #       Add -Force to Get-ChildItem to include *hidden* items.
    #       Add -Force to Remove-Item to *override read-only attributes*
    Get-ChildItem c:\temp\test | Remove-Item -Recurse -WhatIf
    ```
  - Aside from being more concise, this approach has two **crucial advantages**:

    - It **avoids the `-Path` / `-LiteralPath` pitfall**, because `Get-ChildItem` output reliably *binds to a receiving provider cmdlet's `-LiteralPath` parameter*, by *full path*.

      - *How* this happens (via the `.PSPath` property) is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60177977/45375).
    - It **performs much better**, because only a *single* invocation of `Remove-Item` is needed, which receives all its input via the pipeline.

      - For that reason, **`... | ForEach-Object { Some-Cmdlet $_ }` constitutes a general *anti-pattern*** for any `Some-Cmdlet` that is designed to accept pipeline input, as this approach requires a - costly - separate invocation of `Some-Cmdlet` *for each input object*.

---

For the sake of completeness:

- Using `Get-ChildItem` and piping its output to `Remove-Item` is often needed for fine-grained control of what should be deleted.
- In the **case at hand**, however, **`Remove-Item` *alone* would have sufficed**:

  ```bash
  # NOTE: Add -Force to *include hidden items* and override read-only attributes.
  Remove-Item -Path c:\temp\test\* -Recurse -WhatIf
  ```