# When I run get-process \ where handles it doesn't show a handles column, am I missing something?

Tags: powershell, youtube

I'm following a [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UVUd9_k9C6A&t=6936s) from Jeffrey Snover (inventor of Powershell). Arounmd the 2 hour and 3-7 minute mark it is talking about objects in powershell. It's wanting to follow along by getting a process and then selecting and sorting based on the handle of the process. When I try entering the command, it doesn't show a handles column. Here is the code I entered per the video. I'm using Powershell version 7, I think they are on Powershell version 3.

```
PS C:\> get-process |where handles
```

Any insight or assistance is appreciated.

[example of code run not showing handles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2Fix.png)

I was expecting a handles column to the left of the NPM column.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving default property names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38137864/retrieving-default-property-names)

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell strictly separates *data* from its *representation*.

Therefore the *data* operation of filtering by a given property using [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) (`where`) is unrelated to and has no impact on what *display columns* are shown for the filtered [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process) objects.
The latter is solely determined by the [formatting data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Format.ps1xml) associated with this .NET data type.

Thus:

- the `.Handles` property is *available for data processing* on the output objects.
- if you also want to *display* it in the tabular output, pass its name to the `-Property` parameter of [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table)

Note that you'll then have to pass the name of *all* properties you want displayed, e.g.:

```
Get-Process | Where Handles | Format-Table Handles, Id, Name
```

Note that you can use `*` to match *all available* properties:

```
Get-Process | Where Handles | Format-Table Handles, *
```

`.Handles` is an *alias* property of the type-native `.HandleCount` property, which `*` also selects, so you'll get *both* a `Handles` and the equivalent `HandleCount` column.

---

Note:

- `Format-*` cmdlets are strictly only for *for-display* formatting, and their output is therefore not suitable for later data (programmatic) processing.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375) for details.
- By contrast, you can use the [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) cmdlet for constructing simplified / transformed objects from input objects, which *are* suitable for programmatic processing.

  - Such objects don't have associated formatting data; only if you output them to the display, PowerShell automatically selects suitable for-display formatting, by essentially using `Format-Table` or [`Format-List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-list) *behind the scenes*: objects with *4 or fewer* properties result in implicit `Format-Table` formatting, others in implicit `Format-List` formatting.
- Thus, `Get-Process | Where Handles | Select-Object Handles, Id, Name` would result in tabular formatting, whereas you'd get list formatting (each property name-value pair on its own line) with `Get-Process | Where Handles | Select-Object Handles, *`

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55504393/45375) for  more information.